# How to Gate Drift on my laptop?

Tags: pc, asphalt-8

I can drift through turns using key controls, but how to do a gate drift ... especially through gates on a straight road?

I haven't done this without tilt control.

One way I do know is to start a drift and zig-zag my way through the gate without lifting my finger from the side arrow keys, so the car doesn't leave drift mode. But I almost always crash or drive outside the gate.

Is there a better technique for PCs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a technique for this certain problem. First, you have to press the down key, which activates the drift. Then, carefully press the left and right arrow keys to stabilize the car and prevent it from being pulled out of the drift. Whenever you encounter a turn, press the corresponding arrow to drift through the turn. I hope this solves your problem!